# This question is obvious spam

Tags: discussion

This question is spam, it is written by a phony user, it is phrased in an obvious attempt to grab attention, using silly profane acronyms that you have to decipher, but it is asking a legitimate question, and there are interesting things to say about it.

[Lattice QCD and the 5th dimension](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/10961/gdiwtfu-with-lattice-qcd-and-the-5th-dimension)

Should it be closed, or answered?

Similar questions can be asked about obvious commercial spam (answered, in this case, and probably of interest, but clearly written by an advertizing department):

[Plenoptic camera and display](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14502/plenoptic-camera-and-display)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the question in question is obvious spam, it's just not particularly well written. In a case like this I'd say edit it to clarify it (e.g. expand the acronyms, maybe remove some of the "flowery" language) and answer it.

If a question is so badly written that you can't even make sense of it, then voting to close it is probably more appropriate. If a question contains a completely irrelevant link or URL, use a spam flag instead.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm...I had missed the money quote when I view this previously:

> Should I buy a shirt that says: 5DLQCD or STFU?